# Get class input with closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get class `.mGMZs` in input `name=age` with `.closest`, I try it in following demo but i doesn't work as expected, how can I fix it?

```
<div class="age">
    <div class="column">
        <input name="age[0][]" class="mGMZs" placeholder="Age(Geting class this)">
        <div class="p_age">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button>Click Me</button>
</div>


$('button').live('click', function () {
    var class_age = '.' + $(this).closest('div.age').find('input[name="age"]').prop('name');
    alert(class_age);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a little change:

```
.find('input[name*="age"]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8wjC/11/

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
.find('input[name="age"]')
```

With:

```
.find('input.mGMZs')
```

So you can find based on input's class:

```
$('button').live('click', function () {
    var class_age = '.' + $(this).closest('div.age').find('input.mGMZs').prop('name');
    alert(class_age);
});
```